# Unable to Install skype On ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I was trying Last two hour to install Skype on Ubuntu 12.04 
But getting the error

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': Is a directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Any Help would be greatly Appreciated !!!

Comment: I'm using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Skype add the Canonical Partner Repository.Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
```

**Install Skype on Ubuntu 32bit:**

```
wget -O skype.deb http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.8-1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install libxss1
sudo dpkg -i skype.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

**Install Skype on Ubuntu 64bit:**

```
wget -O skype.deb http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.8-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install libxss1 lib32stdc++6 lib32asound2 ia32-libs libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 
sudo dpkg -i skype.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```